# Inventor 2022: Inventor Vault Addin throws error when tries to connect to Vault

Tags: autodesk, vault

I use Inventor 2022. I made some Datastandard customizations and when I try to open the Vault connection through the Vault Addin, I get [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/713Ha.png)

Trying it again, I get [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6faI.png)

Answer (score 0):

Solution: The error occures when in your Datastandard scripts you have codelines outside the functions. Every code line must be inside a function, and it will work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).